# подмена координат от GPS

Tags: android, координаты

Есть куча приложений которые помогают использовать свои координаты подменяя данные от GPS.

Есть задача привязать некую логику движения, подменяя реальные координаты.
Как такое реализовать в своим приложении? 

 Буду признателен за любую информацию по данной теме.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужны размеры View, то можно получать с помощью myView.getMeasuredHeight(), а менять myView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight с шириной соответственно. После вызовите myView.requestLayout(), если это нарушило макет представления.

Comment: Прошу прощения, когда писал вопрос, даже не подумал о координатах View

Comment: ничего не понял, причем тут это?

Comment: Я неверно сформулировал вопрос и ввел человека в заблуждение. Вопрос подредактировал